# Shortest Path using Markov Decision

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-models

For the following question, one solves the problem to find the shortest path from the Start to the End in the following maze using the Markov decision process.
[image]

We formulate this problem as the following:

- The state-space $\mathcal{S}$ consists of the white blocks in the figure. Each element is expressed as $(i, j)$.
- The action space $A=\{N, S, W, E\}$ where $N, S, W$ and $E$ mean that go to north, south, west and east, respectively. However, the next state does not change if the direction of action is blocked. For example,
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  &P((1,3) \mid(1,4), S)=1, \quad P((4,4) \mid(3,4), E)=1 \\
  &P((1,5) \mid(1,5), N)=1, \quad P((4,3) \mid(4,4), S)=1
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- $(1,5)$ is the initial state and $(5,1)$ is the terminal state. ${ }^{2}$
- $R\left(s, a, s^{\prime}\right)=1$ if $s^{\prime}=(5,1)$ and 0 otherwise.
- The discounted factor $\gamma=0.9$.
  Initialize $V_{0}(s)=0$ for all $s \in \mathcal{S}$. Using the Bellman optimal operator
  $$
  (L v)(s)=\sup _{a \in A} \mathbf{E}_{s^{\prime} \sim P(\cdot \mid s, a)}\left[R\left(s, a, s^{\prime}\right)+\gamma \cdot v\left(s^{\prime}\right)\right]
  $$
  set
  $$
  V_{n+1}(s)=\left(L V_{n}\right)(s), \quad n=0,1,2, \cdots .
  $$
  A policy $\pi$ is said to be a greedy policy induced by a value function $V$ if
  $$
  \pi(s) \in \operatorname{argmax}_{a \in A} Q(s, a)
  $$
  where $Q(s, a)=\mathbf{E}_{s^{\prime}}\left[R\left(s, a, s^{\prime}\right)+\gamma V\left(s^{\prime}\right)\right] .$

How is it possible to find the minimum $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that all of the greedy policies induced by $V_{n}$ is an optimal policy?

$\textbf{Note}$: $\pi^{*}$ is said to be an optimal policy if $V^{\pi^{*}}(s)=V^{*}(s)$ for any $s \in \mathcal{S}$ where $V^{*}$ is an optimal value function.

Comment: Any insightful ideas that could help for progressing could be very appreciative!